# Writing from Stream<String> to PrintWriter drops lines

Tags: java

I'm trying to copy all the lines from positions.txt to processed.txt using Java's Stream and PrintWriter. processed.txt is either overwritten or created during each run. positions.txt contains about 80,000 lines of coordinates like this:

```
756.5725, 510.76566, 2
749.746, 506.72214, 3
735.85754, 500.03607, 1
```

Eventually, I plan on performing some stream operations on the coordinates, but right now I'm just trying to copy them without modification.

This is my code:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ImageProcessor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stream<String> inputLines;
        try {
            inputLines = Files.lines(Paths.get("positions.txt"));
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open file.");
            return;
        }

        File processedFile = new File("processed.txt");
        PrintWriter outputWriter;
        try {
            if (!processedFile.exists()) {
                processedFile.createNewFile();
            }

            outputWriter = new PrintWriter(processedFile);
            inputLines.forEachOrdered(outputWriter::println);
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Could not open output file.");
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Failed to create output file.");
        }


    }
}
```

My problem is that some lines are getting dropped when writing to the file.

After I run the program, processed.txt contains about 400 fewer lines of code than positions.txt. When I reduce positions.txt to 40,000 lines, and then to 1000 lines, the same thing happens. Finally, when positions.txt contains only 500 or 100 lines, processed.txt contains nothing at all.

I'd appreciate any pointers on why this is acting like this, and any solutions. Thank you in advance.

Here is the complete positions.txt:
https://gist.github.com/clausworks/1730edb2337227cb0b895eb1bc8b0081#file-positions-txt

Comment: Close the resource. Put `outputWriter.close()` after `inputLines.forEachOrdered(outputWriter::println)`

Comment: I guess that was it. Thank you!

Comment: Or use [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) which will automatically close used resource.

Comment: You also don't need to check whether the file exists and call `createNewFile()`. The file will be created if it doesn't exist when you write into it. It's also unnecessary to use `forEachOrdered()` since it's not a parallel stream, so a regular `forEach()` is enough (as it is in most cases).